# Optimization requests/responses in react/nodejs

Tags: node.js, loops, optimization

so I have problem with optimizing code, accordingly to DRY rule.

I have 2 requests, 2 responses, 2 GETS, 2 POSTS,

I think I should use loop, which changing the number of iterator, but I have problem with syntax.

Here is my fetch from axios:

```
componentDidMount() {

    fetch('http://localhost:3001/getcounterEbook1')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(count => {
      console.log(count);
      console.log(count.count);
      this.setState({counterebook1: count.count});
    }).catch(err => {
    });

    fetch('http://localhost:3001/getcounterEbook2')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(count => {
      console.log(count);
      console.log(count.count);
      this.setState({counterebook2: count.count});
    }).catch(err => {
    });
  }
```

Here is handleClick1,2 function:

```
  handleClick1(e) {
      console.log("Sending ...")
      let data = {
          clicked: true,
      }
        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/counterEbook1', data)
        .then( res => {
            console.log('ok')
        })
        .catch( () => {
            console.log('Message not sent')
        })
    }


  handleClick2(e) {
    console.log("Sending ...")
    let data = {
        clicked: true,
    }
      axios.post('http://localhost:3001/counterEbook2', data)
      .then( res => {
          console.log('ok')
      })
      .catch( () => {
          console.log('Message not sent')
      })
  }
```

How can I transform it into loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use an Object, call it `myObject`, and use `map` like so:

```
const myObject = { 
  'counterebook1' : 'http://localhost:3001/getcounterEbook1', 
  'counterebook2' : 'http://localhost:3001/getcounterEbook2', 
};

class Foo extends Component {

  ....

  for (let [key, url] of Object.entries(myObject)) {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(count => {
        console.log(count);
        console.log(count.count);
        this.setState({key: count.count});
      }).catch(err => {
      });
  }
...
```

You can consolidate `handleClick`s by first retrieving the source that triggered the event, and then using that same object

```
  handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log("Sending ...")
        const url = myObject[e.target.id];
    let data = {
        clicked: true,
    }
      axios.post(url, data)
      .then( res => {
          console.log('ok')
      })
      .catch( () => {
          console.log('Message not sent')
      })
  }
```

Note that we're pulling the `id prop from`e.target`and referencing the key/value pair in`myObject`. This means that the element rendered must have the`id` prop set to some key in myObject:

For example:

```
  <button onClick={this.handleClick} id={key}>
      `Button for ${key}`
  </button>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: It's works, but how can I later call: {this.state.counterebook1}

Comment: And i have problem with setting this.setState to specific state    this.state = {
        counterebook1: '',
        counterebook2:'',
    }